# Where is /tmp/myname located?

Tags: mkdir

When using the following, I understand that I make a directory inside a directory:

```
mkdir /tmp/myname
```

but where is it located?
How can I see its parent folder?

Comment: `ls -Al /tmp`? .

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you actually mean and what your issue is. With your command, you create a directory called `myname` inside the directory `/tmp`.  Therefore, `/tmp` is the parent directory to your new directory. If you want to list the contents of `/tmp`, then use `ls /tmp`.  If you have the pathname `/tmp/myname` in a variable, `$pathname`, then `dirname "$pathname"` would return `/tmp` (as would `dirname /tmp/myname`).  Please clarify your question.

Comment: it is located at `/tmp/myname`. The parent directory is `/tmp`.

Comment: You need to  start reading. You can't expect others to do your homework for you. Then start practising. Install A Unix (such as debian Gnu/Linux) on your own machine (best to use a virtual machine, when you first start), and use it for everything. It will seem difficult at first, but seen you will be glad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In unix filesystems your base directory is not disk like in windows (eg. `c:\`), but "root" - `/`. It is highest level, it contains different system directories, to see them you can do `ls /`, this will print all files and folders in `/`, the structure is something like this:

```
user@computer:~$ tree  -L 1 /
/
├── bin -> usr/bin
├── boot
├── cdrom
├── dev
├── etc
├── home
├── lib -> usr/lib
├── lib32 -> usr/lib32
├── lib64 -> usr/lib64
├── libx32 -> usr/libx32
├── lost+found
├── media
├── mnt
├── opt
├── proc
├── root
├── run
├── sbin -> usr/sbin
├── snap
├── srv
├── swapfile
├── sys
├── tmp
├── usr
└── var
```

As you may see `/` contains directory `tmp`. By running `mkdir /tmp/myname` you have created a directory inside `/` `tmp` and you could find it there. For example you could do `ls /tmp` to see content of tmp.
To learn more about unix filesystems you can [read about it in the internet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_filesystem).
To learn more about each individual command you can run `man mkdir` or google it.

PS: `/tmp` is a special directory for temporary files, it is automatically emptied on reboot, so your folder might already be removed.